# c# string indexing by every 2 elements

Tags: c#, loops, class, oop

Iam trying to make a small decrypter however is there a way I can do a for loop over a string over number e.g "1512120508" by i index ever 2 characters instead of 0 then 1 then 2 etc.. so for example first loop checks index 0 and 1 ("15") then next loop checks 2 and 3 ("12") and so on. Thank you.

```
public string decode(string text)
        {
            string newText = "";
            string transposed = "";

            var encryption = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
                {"a","01"},{"b","02"},{"c","03"},{"d","04"},{"e","05"},
                {"f","06"},{"g","07"},{"h","08"},{"i","09"},{"j","10"},
                {"k","11"},{"l","12"},{"m","13"},{"n","14"},{"o","15"},
                {"p","16"},{"q","17"},{"r","18"},{"s","19"},{"t","20"},
                {"u","21"},{"v","22"},{"w","23"},{"x","24"},{"y","25"},
                {"z","26"}
            };

            for(int i = ; i < text.Length; i)
            {
                if(encryption.ContainsValue(Convert.ToString(text[i])))
                {
                    // finds key from value
                    var myKey = encryption.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == Convert.ToString(text[i])).Key;
                    transposed += myKey;
                }
            }
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter fair play mate,didnt even come across to think of that i wont lie,yeh ill just do that thanks!

Comment: @TimSchmelter oh no it ownt work like that because when i use the normal for loop it still indexes each charcter but the value is 01 02 03 etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `+=2` in the for-loop and `String.Substring`. But i would use a `StringBuilder` and don't use `ContainsValue` + another loop over the dictionary but only one:

```
public static string decode(string text, int length = 2)
{
    StringBuilder transposeBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    var encryption = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
                {"a","01"},{"b","02"},{"c","03"},{"d","04"},{"e","05"},
                {"f","06"},{"g","07"},{"h","08"},{"i","09"},{"j","10"},
                {"k","11"},{"l","12"},{"m","13"},{"n","14"},{"o","15"},
                {"p","16"},{"q","17"},{"r","18"},{"s","19"},{"t","20"},
                {"u","21"},{"v","22"},{"w","23"},{"x","24"},{"y","25"},
                {"z","26"}
            };

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i += length)
    {
        string token = text.Length >= i + length ? text.Substring(i, length) : text.Substring(i);
        var keyValue = encryption.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Value == token);
        if(!keyValue.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, string>)))
        {
            transposeBuilder.Append(keyValue.Key); 
        }
    }
    
    return transposeBuilder.ToString();
}
```

You should consider to store the value in the key and the key in the value to benefit from the dictionary's fast lookup performance. Then you could use this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i += length)
{
    string token = text.Length >= i + length ? text.Substring(i, length) : text.Substring(i);
    if(encryption.TryGetValue(token, out string value))
    {
        transposeBuilder.Append(value); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeh thanks for help i just swapped the key values and used a substring works now cheers again